# Given a power series with interval of convergence $(-1,1]$, construct a series with another given interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Suppose that you have a power series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_nx^n)$$
 whose interval of convergence is $(-1,1]$.

A) Using the same numbers $(a_n)$, come up with a new power series whose interval of convergence is $(0,2]$

B) Using the same numbers $(a_n)$, come up with a new power series whose interval of convergence is $(-2,2]$.

C) Using the same numbers $(a_n)$, come up with a new power series whose interval of convergence is $[-1,1)$. Hint: what transformation would turn the interval $(-1,1]$ into $[-1,1)$?

D) Putting together ideas from the previous parts of this question, come up with a new power series whose interval of convergence is $[10,20)$

For part A I got 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n. $$

For part B I got 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(2x)^n.$$

Part C and D I have no idea. I'm really confused. Can someone explain?

Comment: B is wrong, it's $(x/2)^n$. Google "Mathjax" to learn about formatting on the site and avoid making readers' eyes bleed.

Comment: Hint: this has nothing to do with power series, it is just about transforming an interval into another

Comment: For part (C), consider it this way: If the original interval of convergence had been $(3,5]$, how would you make it $[-5,-3)$?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to the site so I didn't write things correctly. But that's the problem I'm having, I don't know what transformation would change an open bracket to closed bracket and vise versa. It would only change the signs of the numbers in the interval

Comment: @Rivers did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Part b is not quite right. If you have a power series with convergence in $x$ on $(-1,1]$ then you should expand the region by shrinking the variable. In other words if $x=\frac{1}{2}y$ then the interval $(-1,1]$ in terms of $x$ corresponds to the interval $(-2,2]$ in terms of $y$. (To confirm, just consider the end points $x=-1$ and $x=1$).

For c, we know that the power series converges on $(-1,1]$. If we let $x=-y$ then at $x=1$ we have $y=-1$ and the range of $y$ is $[-1,1)$, so

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n (-y)^n$$
has a interval of convergence of $[-1,1)$ in terms of $y$.

In order to answer d you have to consider the steps taken in a, b, and c. We first 'expand' the interval from $(-1,1]$ in terms of $x$ to $(-15,15]$ in terms of $y$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(\frac{y}{15}\right)^n$$

which may then be 'reflected around the center of the interval' to have an interval of convergence of $[-15,15)$ in terms of $z$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(\frac{y}{15}\right)^n 
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(\frac{(-z)}{15}\right)^n$$

which we then 'shift' to $[-10,20)$ in terms of $w$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(-\frac{z}{15}\right)^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(-\frac{(w-5)}{15}\right)^n$$

or more simply
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(\frac{5-w}{15}\right)^n< \infty \quad\text{for $w\in[-10,20)$}$$

Note, for a sanity check we may check the end points. $w=-10$ corresponds to $x=\frac{5-(-10)}{15} = 1$, where the series converges in terms of $x$. Also $w=20$ corresponds to $x=\frac{5-(20)}{15}=-1$ where we know that the series diverges.

Comment: I'm unclear why this was bumped to the main page years after it was first written, but I hope this is of use to someone.

Answer (score 0):

For part (c), consider the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_nx^n(-1)^n)$$

Since when $x =1$, our series becomes: $\sum a_n$, therefore, the series $a_n$ converges.

Therefore, if we want $a_n$ to converge when $x= -1$, by adding $(-1)^n$, when $x =-1$, the series then becomes $\sum (a_n)(-1)^n$. Therefore, if it is multiplied by $(-1)^n$ it will cancel out with the other one and leave our answer to be: $\sum a_n$

You can use this idea to help you answer part (d). of this question, as they are similar in concept.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused with how this changes the interval from (-1, 1] to [-1,1).

Comment: We have that the series $a_n$ converges when $x=1$ given by your initial condition. If we want to maintain this condition, then we must multiply by that factor $(-1)^n$  in order to maintain that condition.